# Is there a way to access a value from another value in the same array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of configuration:

```
return array(
    'admin_url' => 'admin',
    'routes' => array(
        'link1' => 'admin/link1',
        'link2' => 'admin/link2'
     )
);
```

Is it possible to directly get 'admin_url' in 'link1'? Something like:

```
...
'routes' => array(
    'link1' => someDynamicGet.'/link1',
...
```

Tried:

```
return $config = array(
    'admin_url' => 'admin',
    'routes' => array(
        'link1' => $config['admin_url'].'/link1',
        'link2' => $config['admin_url'].'/link2'
     )
);
```

Did not work.

Comment: As in, if the `admin_url` was changed to, `adm` then `link1` and `link2` would be changed to, `adm/link1` and `adm/link2` respectively?

Comment: You should show the logic behind your "dynamically".

Comment: yes, its possible by making an object that behaves similar to an array by implementing ArrayAccess, and then intercepting the __set calls. But, I recommend you just write a regular class and practice your encapsulation skillz.

Comment: What are you going to use this for? Why not define routes to be subpaths? Eg. you don't put the admin_url part there as all but document it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
$retArray = return array(
    'admin_url' => 'admin',
    'routes' => array();
);
$retArray['routes']['link1'] = $retArray['admin_url'].'/link1';
$retArray['routes']['link2'] = $retArray['admin_url'].'/link2';

return $retArray;
```

It's not 'dynamic'. You could possibly do what you want 'dynamically' if you built a class.

Comment: It's a solution, not very elegant, but I will implement it if there's no other solutions. Thanks

Comment: I agree it's not 'elegant' - we can't always have everything! As I said - you might get a more 'elegant' solution with a class, but 'elegant' isn't always 'clearest'.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do something like this:

```
$array = array(0,1,2,$array[1]); //error!
```

But there is something really interesting about this question! You **could** do this:

```
$admin = 'admin';
$array = array('admin_url' => &$admin); //passing by referance
```

Now, when you change the variable `$admin` it also changes in the $array!

```
$admin = 'Ziarno';
echo $array['admin_url']; //echoes 'Ziarno'!
```

However, you **can't** concatenate this to a string:

```
$array2 = array(
'admin_url' => &$admin,
'routes' => array(
    'link1' => &$admin . '/link1', //error!
    'link2' => "$admin/link2"      // will not change when the var $admin changes :(
 )
);
```

So in the end, a simple solution to this would be:

```
$admin = 'admin';

$array = array(
    'admin_url' => $admin,
    'routes' => array(
        'link1' => "$admin/link1",
        'link2' => "$admin/link2"
     )
);
```

However, the $array values will not change *automatically* when $admin changes... but if you're using it as a return value in a function, I think it should work just fine.

```
return $array;
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Jon and others, it is not possible to access the value inside the array declaration.

I don't know in what context you need to achieve this, but if you really need to reconfigure your array I would wrap it up in a function something like this (works in PHP >=5.3 only):

```
function set_config_routes(array $array) {
   $return = array('admin_url'=>$array['admin_url']);
      array_walk_recursive($array, function($val, $key) use (&$return) { 
         if(substr($key,0,4)=='link'){          
            $return['routes'][$key] = $return['admin_url'].$val; 
         }
      });
   return $return;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
$config = set_config_routes($config);
```

As Mike W and others also have stated, you really should look into using Classes and Objects for a more efficient practice.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. You would have to take the value of `admin_url` outside the array declaration in order to refer to it, or else add the elements that refer to it in a separate step.